# no auto generated config with dynamic_reconfigure

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am failing to use the dynamic_reconfigure package to configure my program. Although i have a working config file ( its working in another project ), during the make process, no header file is created. It seems like the dynamic_reconfigure part of the make process is skipped.

I have created a simple test project following the dynamic reconfigure tutorial

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

add_executable( blaa main.cpp )

rosbuild_find_ros_package(dynamic_reconfigure)
include(${dynamic_reconfigure_PACKAGE_PATH}/cmake/cfgbuild.cmake)
gencfg()
```

main.cpp

```
 #include "ros/ros.h"
 #include "blaa/defaultConfig.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "blaa");
 
    return 0;
 }
```

manifest.xml

```
 <package>
   <description brief="blaa">
      blaa
   </description>
   <author>agv</author>
   <license>BSD</license>
   <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
   <url>http://ros.org/wiki/blaa</url>
   <depend package="rospy"/>
   <depend package="roscpp"/>
   <depend package="dynamic_reconfigure"/>

 </package>
```

Output of make ( with a bit of configure )

```
 ~/ros/stacks/magv/blaa$ make
 [rosbuild] Building package blaa
 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
 [rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
 MSG: gencfg_cpp on:default.cfg
 Finding dependencies for /home/agv/blaa/cfg/default.cfg
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: /home/agv/blaa
 [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/blaa.dir/main.o
 /home/agv/blaa/main.cpp:2:32: fatal error: blaa/defaultConfig.h: No such      file or directory
 compilation terminated.
 make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/blaa.dir/main.o] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/blaa.dir/all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ignoring the obvious compilation error at the end. It seems like the build process just skipps the config generation ( it starts at 50%). Any idea why?

Thank you for your time!
Manuel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12211/no-auto-generated-config-with-dynamic_reconfigure/) by [momus](https://answers.ros.org/users/1285/momus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i finally found the mistake. In the CMakeList.txt i was using the wrong statement to define the target executable.

Instead of

```
 add_executable( blaa main.cpp )
```

It must read

```
 rosbuild_add_executable( blaa main.cpp )
```

Only if so, ros libraries are linked against the target executable and the pre compilation steps like message and config generation is done.

Thank you or your time.

---

Originally posted by [momus](https://answers.ros.org/users/1285/momus/) with karma: 41 on 2011-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0